# Copy identity and put it to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day! I'm having trouble with my stored procedure, here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CS_RefQuestionChoice(ChoiceDescription, QuestionID, RatingID, SetID)

SELECT @choice, @@IDENTITY,@ratingid,1 FROM CS_RefQuestions
```

The code is running smoothly, but I'm having trouble because it saves 75 records on my database, it should save only one, all I want this to execute is when I save another choice, it should save also the latest primary key of the CS_RefQuestions for relationship purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I misunderstood your question but it seemed that you can solve the problem using `OUTPUT` clause in `INSERT` statement - one of descriptions you can find in [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/06/13/output-clause.aspx)

Comment: I can't believe that that's been there since SQL Server 2005!   That is a really handy extension.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.CS_RefQuestionChoice
       ( ChoiceDescription, 
         QuestionID, 
         RatingID, 
         SetID
       )
SELECT choice, 
       QuestionChoiceID, 
       ratingid,
       1 
  FROM CS_RefQuestions   
  WHERE QuestionChoiceID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I'm presuming a name of `QuestionChoiceID` for the identity column in the CS_RefQuestions table.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ident int    
SET @ident = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO dbo.CS_RefQuestionChoice 
    (ChoiceDescription, 
             QuestionID, 
             RatingID, 
             SetID
           )
    SELECT choice, 
           @ident, 
           ratingid,
           1 
      FROM CS_RefQuestions
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ident int    
SET @ident = IDENT_CURRENT(dbo.CS_RefQuestionChoice) AS Current_Identity
INSERT INTO dbo.CS_RefQuestionChoice(ChoiceDescription, QuestionID, RatingID, SetID)

SELECT @choice, @ident ,@ratingid,1 FROM CS_RefQuestions
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the feedback, much appreciated. I know my question is hard to understand however I'm able to answer my question with the help of a friend. here's the code I needed:

```
USE [CCBBS_Survey_DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveNewQuestionChoice]
@question VARCHAR(200),
@choice VARCHAR(100),
@qno INT,
@categid int,
@ratingid int
AS
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT QuestionNo FROM CS_RefQuestions where QuestionNo = @qno)
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO CS_RefQuestions(Question,QuestionNo,CategoryID, SetID)
         VALUES (@question, @qno, @categid, 1)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  CS_RefQuestions 
        SET     Question = @question
                ,CategoryID = @categid
        WHERE QuestionNo = @qno
    END

 DECLARE @QUI INT

 SET @QUI = (SELECT TOP(1) QuestionID FROM CS_RefQuestions where QuestionNo = @qno)


 INSERT INTO dbo.CS_RefQuestionChoice(ChoiceDescription, QuestionID, RatingID, SetID)

 SELECT @choice, @QUI, @ratingid,1 FROM CS_RefQuestions RQ

 WHERE QuestionID = @QUI 

END
```

Comment: That will not work in a multi-user environment:  `SELECT TOP` would not be guaranteed to return the ID of the record you just inserted.   You should use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead.